# Coax through wall box

Tags: wiring, coaxial-cable

Trying to hook up a coax port that the builders didn't finish. House built last year. They finished one coax port and left the other three with the wire ran but not capped. This box has the wire going straight through it. Foamed at the top and going out the bottom. This is on an exterior wall and there's nothing it would be going to inside or out. I've confirmed the other end is just open ended. I expected to be able to pull the wire out of the bottom of the box but it's not coming. Any ideas what is going on here? Should I just cut it so I can use it?

[image]

Comment: Coax doesn’t require a sealed box, I might break the back of the box out especially if the line is tight as this is they may have planned a distribution point here but accidentally pulled the loop tight. Pulling on the cable may damage it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, especially if you can see the end is free. If you think there's enough in the box to get a connector on, then just cut it and activate the box.

If you'd like to try and get more wire, then use pliers with their teeth wrapped a couple of times with electrical or duct tape. As long as you don't try too hard and rip the wire open, you won't damage anything.

Likely, you just need to break the foam's initial sticky area to slide the wire. Go straight in at the top or bottom of the box (top if pulling down and bottom if you're pulling up).

Use the outer edge of the box as your lever's (pliers) folcrum and pull up or push down (see above) the plier handles while gripping the wire tightly. This will usually provide much greater power and pop the foam's seal.

Comment: Never could pull it through the bottom. I was able to push it up through the top about an inch. Guess they stapled top and bottom. But I cut it and had more than enough to put an end on it.

Comment: That's great and great job, I'm glad it worked out! It's always nice to find something useful and finally finish it off and get it complete.